# Error:Execution failed for task ' App:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android, android-studio, colors, error-handling

I have converted Eclipse project into studio (.gradle file),import this project into studio i got below error,please help me to solve this problem.

```
Error:Error: Duplicate resources: E:\workspace\application\res\values\setting_color.xml:color/default_bg, E:\workspace\application\res\values\colors.xml:color/default_bg
:ApplicationFAILED
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 19.189 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: any one help me out this

Comment: Just remove the duplicate resource in your colors.xml file, exceptions says  like that, Android studio have inbuild inspection profiles which automatically run when project is in build stage.

Comment: thank u somuch @Brendon